# Why won't this increment?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a php shopping cart guide, I'm up to a section where when I add a product to the cart and the product increments each time the add to cart link is clicked, but mine doesn't, it only shows 1 and doesn't increments any further. When I go back to products (index.php) page the cart doesn't hold that data, the guide says it should but mine doesn't. How can I have it increment each time the add to cart link is pressed? Can anyone see something I've missed or done wrong?

**index.php:**

```
<?php 
require("connect.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM elec_guit ORDER BY name ASC"; 
$query=mysql_query($sql); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
 ?> 

    <div class="price1">
        <p>
            $<?php echo $row['price'] ?> 
            <br>
            <br>
            <!-- This is correct now -->
            <a href="cart.php?add=<?php echo $row['id_product'] ?>">Add to cart</a>
        </p>
    </div>


<?php 

}
```

?>

**This is the cart.php:**

```
 <?php

session_start();


$page = 'cart.php';

include ('connect.php');

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=+'1';

}



    echo $_SESSION ['cart_1'];


?>
```

**UPDATE**

OK so it's all sorted now, I tried it on another lamp stack and it works, mine wasn't functioning properly somewhere, thanks for all the help with trying to work this one out

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=+'1';` is wrong, do you mean, `$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] += 1;`?

Comment: Okay you need to check first if it is set. So `$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] = !isset($_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]) ? 1 : $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] + 1;`

Comment: No change at all for either changes @timhysniu

Comment: remove the space in your echo statement `$_SESSION['cart_1']`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] = intval($_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]) + 1;
```

Comment: It still won't increment the number, and the data is lost as soon as I go back to index

Answer (score 0):

In general, `session_start()` will start a session that is not yet started or give you access to an existing session. when you navigate away from the cart page and back to the index page (which doesn't have `session_start()`) you won't be able to see the session variable.

The script you have creates the 'cart_X' element of the `$_SESSION` array, where X is whatever is in `$_GET['add']`, corresponding to a product id. Consider separating the cart from the objects contained in it as follows:

```
session_start();
$product_id = $_GET['add'];
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]){
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 1;
}
```

Note that the above doesn't check for bogus input (always a good idea to validate input server-side as well as client-side). Aside from that, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, move to `mysqli_*` if possible.

Instead of `echo $_SESSION['cart_1']` try `print_r($_SESSION['cart'])` between `<pre>` tags to see what's in the cart, and put `session_start()` in your index page as well if you need access to the variable there.

Answer (score 0):

+'1'  will cast '1' to an positive int(1) :p

see what this give you,

```
var_dump(+1,-1,+'1',-1,-'1');
```

thus

```
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=+'1';
```

is the same as

```
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=(int)'1';
```

you're basically doing

```
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=1;
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=1;
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=1;
```

when what you WANT is

```
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+=1;
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+=1;
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+=1;
```

there's also other problems with your code, which error_reporting(E_ALL); will tell you about - 
    $*SESSION['cart*'.$_GET['add']]  is never initialized, i know, adding to an uninitialized variable *WORKS* in php because php is stupid, but you shouldn't do it, and you will get an E_NOTICE error.
you can correctly initialize it like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']])){//variable not initialized, initialize it.
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]=1;
} else {
$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+=1;
}
```

and mysql_ functions has been deprecated since 5.5.0, you should port your code to PDO or mysqli , you'll find an excellent guide here http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: changing =+1 to +=1 makes no difference to the incremented value, I think the actual issue lies within the session, whenever I leave the page all data is reset. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, most likely cookies are not loaded or sent properly